# cannot change php error reporting level on my staging server .,any comments will be appricated

Tags: php, xampp

i have set error reporting to 1 using php function error_reporting(1) but it has no effect on the server .actually i am working on a staging server using  xampp.is there any settings which has to be enabled in server so that php error reporting settings can be changed.

Answer (score 1):

just make .htaccess file and to it add

```
##Turn off display_errors##
php_flag display_errors off
```

save it into main directory
and its done

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the setting in `\xampp\php\php.ini`, not via the `error_reporting` function. Then restart the server, and you should be good to go.

You may also want to check that `display_errors` is set to on. (Off the top of my head, though, XAMPP should be configured to display errors by default. Weird.)

---

Via FTP only, you can attempt to set these variables via `ini_set` at the top of your script:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1)
ini_set('error_reporting', 1)

?>
```

You may also want to try setting these variables through a `.htaccess` file. Create a file called `.htaccess` in the same directory as your script, and add these lines:

```
php_flag display_errors on
php_value error_reporting 1
```

Comment: actually i have only ftp permissions on the server ..is there any other way.@primatology

Answer (score 0):

Put this line `ini_set('display_errors',1);` on the top of your php code.

Comment: will this override the server settings?